# PHP MySQL Name Score separation system

Tags: php, mysql, formatting, explode

I've got a website which lists sports scores. It current works like this:

Firstname Lastname 1-0 Firstname Lastname

It explodes this based on spaces, then explodes the third one (containing the scores) based on the - .

The problem with this is that it does not support names with more than 2 words. If I explode using - first, it would not support names with - in there. The results are added in a textarea, because I have many thousands that need to be added, so I don't want to make multiple fields to input data into, as I can currently add matches quickly listing one result per line. Does anyone have advice on how to make the system both multi-word, and special character-insensitive? Is there maybe a way to split when it encounters a number, then select the first chunk as the first name, the last as that players score, and the rest as the last name?

Comment: You should look into regular expressions - they can do what you want

Comment: sounds like poor database design...

Comment: @Flukey That's what I thought at first, but it sounds like this is a data entry format and not a data storage format. I think the OP is either typing these in or scraping them from elsewhere, and then trying to break them into meaningful chunks.

Comment: @octern You're right, I'm adding sports results into a text area, to facilitate adding loads of matches quickly. I'm working with a players table, a matches table etc, and in order to keep statistics need to store players names and the scores in the match separately.

Comment: @Damp Figured it out, that did exactly what I want, thanks a million!

preg_match("#(.*)(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})(.*)#", $string, $array);
Then simply explode the 2 name elements according to first word being first name, rest being last name.

What do I click to thank Damp ? Is there a reputation button somewhere? :)

Comment: That looks like it works for separating the names from the score, but I think there are still special names that might trip you up. For example, two first names, or middle initials. Regarding your other question, you can only reward damp if they change their comment into a formal answer. If they do, you can remove the check mark from my answer and select it for their answer instead. Once your reputation is over 15, you can also upvote answers.

Comment: @octern 2 first names would be a problem, but in 1600 players I've not come across one yet, so fingers crossed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's any way to teach a simple parsing command, or even a regular expression, to do what you want. Some cases will always be ambiguous. For example, if you have the names `Mary Ann Steiner" and "Constantin Van Dyke" the patterns are exactly the same, but one needs to be split (2/1) and the other needs to be split (1/2).

You could possibly find a library that knows how to make educated guesses based on a huge dictionary of known names, but failing that...

I think in this case you need the human brain inputting the data to make some of the decisions, and indicate them during data entry. In my experience using multiple fields isn't that slow if you navigate using the tab key instead of mousing around. You could also enter the data using a delimiter of your own, like:

```
Mary Ann,Steiner,2-3
Constantin,Van Dyke,4-2
```

Then you'd run something that explodes those lines based on "," and enters the elements into your db.

If you're copy/pasting or scraping the data from an external site, another option would be to just explode every line using the method you're currently using. This should work for most records, and when it doesn't work, it will be obvious -- the resulting record will have too many elements. You can have your script flag just those records for human intervention.

Comment: Valid, well thought out answer, although I have managed a slightly more automated way with regular expressions. Thanks for the help anyway!